# Recursive spawner instantiating way too many gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a recursive function that will instantiate a bird at a random interval of time between a min and max value, and then call itself so that the process starts over and a new bird will be instantiated after another random interval.  The problem is that currently after the first random interval passes an infinite (close) number of birds are being instantiated all at once.  But I don't see where I went wrong.  SpawnBird() has been tested and only instantiates one bird when called on its own.

```
void Start()
{
    minBirdWait = 10;
    maxBirdWait = 25;
    BirdGenerator();
}

void BirdGenerator()
{
    float timer = Random.Range(minBirdWait, maxBirdWait);
    Invoke("SpawnBird", timer);
    BirdGenerator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up turning it into a coroutine and it works now.

```
IEnumerator BirdGenerator()
{
    while(true)
    {
        float timer = Random.Range(minBirdWait, maxBirdWait);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
        SpawnBird();
    }
}
```